# Laravel 5.4 post request token mismatch

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5

I am learning to create API in Laravel. I created a CRUD controller, and I have an empty store function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd('store');
}
```

When I try to make a post request with Postman I get the token mismatch exception:

```
"Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException">TokenMismatchException in
   "/Users/andrei/Desktop/api.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68">VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68
```

I have no form for the post method to put {{csrf.. }}. How can this be solved? Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729415/disable-csrf-in-laravel-for-specific-route

Comment: for example if I have the route: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/lessons/ for get and post, What do I put in the except for csrf?

Comment: Current documentation link: https://laravel.com/docs/master/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Comment: @Samsquanch bro your username, +100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For APIs, you should exclude them from CSRF by using the `$except` property in the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware.

Comment: if my route is localhost:8000/api/v1/lessons what should I put in the $except variable?

Comment: I would do something like this to exclude all routes that contain `api/`: `protected $except = [
        'api/*'
    ];`

Comment: This solved my problem! As I will get more rating, I will vote up

Answer (score 1):

If you use form submission you have to use `{{ csrf_field() }}` which will be rendered to be `<input type='hidden' name='_token' value="tokenvalueofcharsans numbers" />`. But if you just send ajax request and you can't set a `{{ csrf_field() }}` in your request, you have to:

 1- exclude your url from the csrf verification by adding your url in `$except` variable in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken` middleware.

2- Find a way to verify csrf not to be affected in this track.

Comment: for example if I have the route: localhost:8000/api/v1/lessons for post, What do I put in the $except?

Comment: put the url route you put in `App/Http/routes.php` as `Route::post('**yourroute**', 'YourController@yourMethod')`. The mentioned yourroute