# How to Post stream_id, stream_url, data, status to the Acrcloud callback url and write to the txt file

Tags: laravel-5.8

Note: i try to post all info of advertises from acrcloud to the my local txt file and save the data.

I am working on laravel 5.8

my AcrCloud callback Url : http://medya.guru/list

Note 2: i have a cron job command also this is;
curl -s medya.guru/list >/dev/null
it is working every minute ,

The function data() in the controller is ;

```
public  function data(){
   $filename =  storage_path('tmp/monitor_result.lst');
   $stream_result = array();
   $stream_result['stream_id'] = $_POST['stream_id'];
   $stream_result['stream_url'] = $_POST['stream_url'];
   $stream_result['stream_data'] = json_decode($_POST["data"], true);  #monitor result body.
   $stream_result['stream_status'] = $_POST["status"];  ##status=0 means data is No Result.

//save result to mysql, redis or file
   file_put_contents($filename, json_encode($stream_result)."\n", FILE_APPEND);
   echo "ok";
    }
```

Note 1: I get a post null 
{"stream_id":null,"stream_url":null,"stream_data":null,"stream_status":null}

Comment: note: advertises are recognizing and  listing in the acrcloud,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error Msg：419, Page Expired
This because Laravel has CSRF verification, please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729415/disable-csrf-in-laravel-for-specific-route) to set it.