# How to set intended route in an array

Tags: laravel, routes

Hi I am working on laravel project and integrated payment method, there is requirement of payment method to pass redirectURL which is based on POST method, however passing normal route it through error of 419. So is there any way to attach csrf token with route method or pass intended route in an array.
There is screenshot of my code.

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EGbm.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729415/disable-csrf-in-laravel-for-specific-route

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the csrf token check in your application for that redirect URL by adding  the URI path to  VerifyCsrfToken class inside `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` Middleware .

See the example below Where `/payment/callback` is the redirect URI

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
  /**
    * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
    *
    * @var array
  */
   protected $except = [
    '/payment/callback'
    ];
}
```

Passing the csrf token might not solve your problem except the payment partner agrees to include the token in the redirected request payload.