# iFrame loading via chrome and safari - status of 419

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress, iframe, csrf-token

On a WordPress website, I'm attempting to load an iframe. In Mozilla, it functions flawlessly, but just portions of the page are visible on Chrome and Safari. I encountered a console error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 419 (unknown status)

I know it is a CSRF Token, but I cannot figure out why it functions in some places but not others. How can this be resolved, please?

One of the solutions I discovered online is this:

> To solve the 419 HTTP Response Error for Laravel servers, you can use CSRF Token or Exclude URIs from CSRF Protection.

But how do I go about doing it?

Comment: What has this to do with Laravel?

Comment: Is the iframe a laravel website?

Comment: I think this will answer your question issue about CSRF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729415/disable-csrf-in-laravel-for-specific-route

Comment: _"but I cannot figure out why it functions in some places but not others."_ - most likely that would probably be due to problems with 3rd-party cookies, which mean you don't pick up an existing session with each request, but start a new one all the time, and then session-based CSRF can hardly work.

Comment: Because of the CSRF token, I'm assuming the iframe site I'm trying to load on my WordPress site is using Laravel, although I could be wrong.

When I google error 419, Laravel always mentions it.

Can I turn off CSRF protection for URIs?